# How to pull next 2 quarter data with a data model that doesn't have fiscal time database and company defined fiscal year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to pull all orders from the current, next and next to next quarter of the time stamp. I am able to pull up current quarter data but I am not able to pull next and next+1 quarter data.

I am currently using MS SQL Server 2013.

The time stamp also appears in a weird format. for eg.20191031_FY20_Q1_Wk1 whereas [Order Close Fiscal Year Quarter Display Code] appears as 2020-Q1. So to pull current quarter data I have used below condition:
(LEFT(Time_Stamp,2)+'20'+'-'+substring(Time_Stamp,15,2)) = [Order Close Fiscal Year Quarter Display Code]

What I logically want to do is this:
(LEFT(Time_Stamp,2)+'20'+'-'+substring(Time_Stamp,15,2)) = [Order Close Fiscal Year Quarter Display Code] + 1
(LEFT(Time_Stamp,2)+'20'+'-'+substring(Time_Stamp,15,2)) = [Order Close Fiscal Year Quarter Display Code] + 2

Obviously, I came across data type conversion error. I even tried using Dateadd() function:

[Opportunity Close Fiscal Year Quarter Display Code] = DATEADD(quarter,1, cast(left(time_stamp,8) as date) )

but still I keep coming across same error.

The MOST IMPORTANT THING I would like to HIGHLIGHT is my org's Fiscal Year is not same as generic Fiscal Year. In my org, Fiscal Year begins from Oct and ends in Sep. So I am not sure how even DateAdd() function will help. I believe having a Fiscal Time table customized as per org's Fiscal Year could be of great help for me but my manager thinks the BI team won't entertain such a request.

Any help in building this query would be really great!!

Comment: It's somewhat surprising to me that an organization that has a non-calendar fiscal year would not already have a custom calendar table defined. You need one. Ask for it. If you get turned down, ask again the next time someone needs data parsed by the corporate calendar (probably tomorrow). Then ask again the time after that. Until you have the table that you and everyone else in the company needs.

Comment: I completely agree with you. Every company I have worked with before has had time dimension table. Our company also has it but my manager is of the opinion that due to some internal politics,the team responsible for the data model I am working with may not import it :(

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to have `time_stamp` values whose format is not as you describe. 
 You should find the column values that don't convert to a date:

```
select time_stamp
from t
where try_cast(left(time_stamp, 8) as date) is null and time_stamp is not null
```

With this information, you can debug your code or the data.